# Lepton flavour violation

Tags: neutrinos, weak-interaction, leptons

I was reading about the evidence of lepton flavour violation coming from the observation
of neutrino oscillations, and was wondering whether this could also lead to LVF in weak interactions or not. Are they two distinct phenomena? Also why don't we observe the
same for down-type leptons?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a down-type lepton?

Comment: I guess I really should have said, charged lepton ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the [Mu2e experiment at Fermilab](http://mu2e.fnal.gov/) is designed to investigate. As the name suggests this will look for evidence of muons changing either directly to electrons or to an electron plus a photon. If you have a lot of spare time the 562 page project description is [available on the Arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.7019). It'll be a few years before they have any results.

I'm not sure what you mean by a *down-type lepton*. Are you getting mixed up with quarks?

Comment: Hello John, thanks for your answer! For down-type lepton I mean electrons, muons, and taus. AFAIK they are typically represented as the lower entry in a weak isospin left-handed doublet, but maybe this is just a matter of convention. I think you answered already to the second part of the question!

Comment: @FredS: aha, OK. So I was correct that you were asking if we see the same sort of oscillation in the electron-muon-tau that we see in the neutrinos. The answer is "not yet but watch this space" :-)